# Аналог NULLIF в 1С 8.3

Tags: 1с

Есть ли во встроенном языке запросов 1С аналог конструкции [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177562.aspx)?

Пример применения функции в Transact-SQL:

```
DECLARE @var int = 0;
SELECT NULLIF(@var, 0) AS Result;
------------------------
Result   
NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот это не подойдёт?

> Функция ISNULL (альтернативное написание ЕСТЬNULL) - если поле имеет
>   тип NULL, то оно заменяется на второй параметр функции.    Синтаксис: 
>   ЕСТЬNULL(<Поле>, <ПодставляемоеЗначение>)   Пример использования:
>
> ```
> Запрос.Текст =
> //Выбираем всю номенклатуру и остатки по ней
> //если остатков, но какой-то номенклатуре нет то будет поле
> //NULL которое заменится значением 0
> "ВЫБРАТЬ
> |    Ном.Ссылка,
> |    ЕСТЬNULL(ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.ВНаличииОстаток, 0) КАК Остаток
> |ИЗ
> |    Справочник.Номенклатура КАК Ном   |     ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрНакопления.ТоварыНаСкладах.Остатки КАК ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки
> |        ПО (ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.Номенклатура = Ном.Ссылка)";
> ```
>
> Также отметим, что тип NULL желательно ВСЕГДА заменять на какое-то
>    значение, т.к. сравнение с типом NULL всегда дает ЛОЖЬ даже если вы
>    сравниваете NULL с NULL. Чаще всего значения NULL образуются в
>    результате соединения таблиц (все виды соединений кроме внутреннего).

Comment: Нет, нужен именно `NULLIF`. Конструкция с `ВЫБОР` меня не устраивает

Answer (score 1):

Операции NULLIF и ее аналогов не существует в языке запросов для платформы «1С:Предприятие 8».

Для решения поставленной задачи можно воспользоваться "ПОЛНЫМ (ВНЕШНИМ) СОЕДИНЕНИЕМ" с заранее подготовленными временными таблицами со значениями NULL для определенных значений. Но так же не стоит забывать что такое решение будет очень медленно работать для версионных баз данных, например, PostgreSQL.

Answer (score -1):

Во встроенном SQL 1C версии 8.3 функция NULLIF() - реализована.

Если же Вам нужен аналог NULLIF, то Вам придётся организовывать его самостоятельно с использованием оператора CASE:

```
CASE WHEN выражение1 = выражение2
     THEN NULL
     ELSE выражение1
     END
```

Comment: Спасибо, но нет

Comment: Кстати, почему `CASE`, а не `ВЫБОР`?

Comment: @Anatol Да потому что тупо не вспомнил, как у одноэсников звучит CASE в обрусификованной версии. А онлайн-мануал по одноэсному SQL навскидку не попался.

Comment: Я не просто так спрашиваю про `CASE` - видел 1С-ные конструкции именно в SQL-синтаксисе и с `NULLIF`. Не могу найти как такое применять

Comment: Проверил ещё раз - действительно, NULLIF в 8-й версии реализована, я ошибся. `Не могу найти как такое применять` Типичное применение - это проверка некоего значения, и вывод его только в случае, когда оно не равно заданному (т.е. скрыть заданные). Ещё одно забавное применение - избежать деления на ноль: `SELECT field1 / NULLIF(field2, 0), ...`

Comment: @Akina, стоит почистить ответ от _[удалено]_. А то сейчас текст весьма странно выглядить

Comment: @Grundy Сделал.

Comment: Вы не понимаете вопроса. Как такое применять в конструкциях 1С я спрашивал. Применение функции я сам продемонстрировал в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Примеры из 1С-запросов с использованием `NULLIF` можете привести?

Comment: @Anatol да они пухлые же... ну вот например тут нашлись запросы с этой функцией: http://www.1cpp.ru/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1386848956/16

Comment: @Akina - 1с++ - это для платформы 7.7

Comment: @Akina извините, но Ваш ответ и комментарии не компетентны. Во-первых они не соответствуют действительности, а во-вторых не отвечают на вопрос. Рекомендовал бы отредактировать или удалить

Comment: @Anatol Цитирую вопрос: `Есть ли во встроенном языке запросов 1С аналог конструкции NULLIF?`. Цитирую ответ: `Во встроенном SQL 1C версии 8.3 функция NULLIF() - реализована.`. Вот теперь (только честно) - отвечает ли этот ответ на вопрос? соответствует ли он действительности? Может, есть смысл с учётом обсуждения сначала ещё раз обдумать и откорректировать/дополнить сам вопрос?

Comment: @Akina Ваши слова ничем не подтверждены. Дайте ссылку на документацию или приведите пример использования. А вот теперь давайте честно - Вы не компетентны в этом вопросе, зачем пытаться выдавить из себя нечто, что ничего, кроме недоумения не вызывает?

Comment: @Anatol `Дайте ссылку на документацию` Вы знаете место в Интернете, где есть в свободном доступе официальная документация на 1С? Мне о существовании такого ресурса неизвестно, если не затруднит - поделитесь... `А вот теперь давайте честно - Вы не компетентны в этом вопросе` - да не вопрос.

Comment: @Akina *Вы знаете место в Интернете, где есть в свободном доступе официальная документация на 1С?* - ну Вы же откуда-то принесли сюда это утверждение о том, что функция реализована.

Comment: Попросил посмотреть в книжке того, у кого она есть. Человек посмотрел, сказал - описана такая. Я ретранслировал эти сведения сюда.